# Python - update plot based on a timer

Tags: python, matplotlib, timer

I have a list of 2D arrays that I plot them using a slider from `matplotlib`. 
I added some control buttons to my plot, so I want to click a `play` button, and the plot changes with some time interval. 
Here's the function that is called by the button:

```
def play(mouse_event):    
    for x in range(len(listOfMoments)):
        image.set_data(listOfMoments[x]) 
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(x)
```

The `print(x)` shows that x is increasing normally, however, it plots only the last array of the list, after the increment finishes.
My question is: How can I make it plot the array one by one, as it expected to be?

I should mention also that I tried the `while` loop and got the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the backend to update the figure after changing the data each time through the loop:

```
fig.canvas.draw()
```

Here's the [documentation reference](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.draw.html).

If you don't have a reference to the `Figure` object, you can probably retrieve it with `fig = plt.gcf()`.

Comment: That what was missing. I just added `fig.canvas.draw()` and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might also use a timer with a callback instead of sleep so that you retain interactivity during the delay. See https://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/timers.html